# populating JS array in specific indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi so this may sound odd but lets say currently I am doing this:

```
 var post_data  = $('input[name="checks[]"]:checked').map(function() {
         return this.value;
        }).get();
```

to get contents of multiple checkboxes into an array to send via AJAX. Now what I ACTUALLY want to do is to construct post_data in a specific way.

I want the value of the checkbox to be stored in the location of the array matching its value. I hope that makes sense :S

so lets say my values of the checkboxes were:

1,5,3,7

i want post_data to be constructed like:

post_data[1] = 1
post_data[5] = 5 etc.

ignoring the fact this may seem stupid, can anyone help me out, I am struggling right now. This is what I was trying, but my very slim knowledge is getting the better of me:

**EDIT UPDATE:** (code progress)

```
var post_data = $('input[name="checks[]"]:checked').serialize();

        alert(post_data);

        $.post('search_item.php', { 'checks[]':post_data,..
```

many thanks,

Comment: Any possibility you could just send it as `checks[]=1&checks[]=3&checks[]=5` etc. and just process it into the form you need it on the server?  That seems to be a more normal mode of operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should initialize `post_data` as an object

```
var post_data = {};
```

here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/kXhWt/1/)

Comment: i don't quite follow, I am not very experience with this stuff at all. ;(

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  `value` is a string.  You want a number.  Use `parseInt()` to turn that string into a number:

```
post_data[parseInt(value)] = value;
```

Comment: ok so Ive made this change, however currently, the array doesn't appear to be getting posted. :S thank you for helping me out. updated with code.

Comment: @buymypies That sounds like a new question.  Please leave this question to one question, instead of an ongoing help forum.

Comment: @buymypies No worries, just recommending the best approach according to the guidelines of the site, so that your question (which is preserved for history) may potentially help other users in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a solution using HTML and serialize(). If you construct each check box with the array number in the name then you will get the result that you are looking for.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" value="3" class="retain_array_value_checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[5]" value="5" class="retain_array_value_checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="1" class="retain_array_value_checkbox" />
```

Now the JS:

```
var post_data  = $('input.retain_array_value_checkbox:checked').serialize();
```

I can't test this, but it should work.  Simple and clean :)

Comment: i havent used serialize before, can I use like so: `$.post('search_item.php', { 'data: serialized_data , ....` ?

Comment: yes, it is passed with the data option. the [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/] documentation gives some examples.

Comment: currently post_data is just empty. Ive updated my code with what I am trying.

Comment: You will need to use a class name to get all the :checked elements and fill in the name attributes with the corresponding number.